# select elements of a dataframe according to the category of a row or column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, dataset, p-value

For each of the 4 genes(each gene is on column), i need to test whether its mean expression is equal for patients with stable and progressive disease and store the corresponding p-value. Someone can help me please ? the language is in R.
Here picture of my dataframe:

[image: dataframe]

Comment: is it possible for you to not use an image? like if your data.frame is called df, do dput(head(df,6)) and paste the output? This way we can work with your data.frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose this is your data frame:

```
df = data.frame(y=sample(c("progres.","stable"),100,replace=TRUE),matrix(rnorm(100*4),ncol=4))
colnames(df)[-1] = c("X1000_at","X1001_at","X1002_at","X1003_at")
```

If you just need the p.value, you can do:

```
apply(df[,-1],2,function(i)t.test(i ~ df$y)[["p.value"]])
  X1000_at   X1001_at   X1002_at   X1003_at 
0.14861795 0.11653459 0.01820033 0.41873270
```

In the above, you iterate through the gene columns, t.test between groups demarcated by the `y` column and capture only the p value.

Comment: thank you for your help it was what i needed, but what is the column 'dm' of the dataframe that you returned in the second example that you gave me ?

Comment: it's the difference in the means. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/genefilter/versions/1.54.2/topics/rowFtests

Comment: thanks, but there are differents p.value between the first example and the second one . it's normal ?

Comment: yes, the second is meant to be an approximation, if you have a lot of columns to iterate through. Sorry I did not mention that. If you have only 4 columns and want an exact p-value, use the apply(...)

Comment: so if i have the same dataframe with 10000 columns, what is the way to recover p_values ? (what is the code)

Comment: Ok I have edited the answer. hopefully this clears up the confusion. Just use the apply code above. It will take a bit longer, but it it will not raise any issues.Hope this solves the problem now